# How to animate the sprite along with action in Cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d

Cocos2d-android - I have an animation which has 5 Frames they are close cropped images. Now I want Sprite to do animation as well as Move in X direction.i.e. I have a player running which gets collided with obstacle and falls down .. Now I want sprite to run animation as well as moveBy in -ve x direction

```
gameOverAnimation =CCSprite.sprite("gmovr00")
gameOverAnimation.setAnchorPoint(0, 0);
gameOverAnimation.setPosition(340.0f, 200.0f);
addChild(gameOverAnimation,10);
CCIntervalAction action1 = CCAnimate.action(mEndAnimation, false);
action1.setDuration(1.0f);
CCIntervalAction delay = CCDelayTime.action(0.68f);
CCMoveBy actionBy = CCMoveBy.action(1.0f, CGPoint.ccp(-340,0)); 
CCIntervalAction seq1 = CCSpawn.actions(action1,actionBy);
//CCSpawn spawn = CCSpawn.actions(action1, actionBy);
                CCSequence sequence1 = CCSequence.actions(seq1,CCCallFuncN.action(this,"gameOver"));
                gameOverAnimation.runAction(sequence1);
```

Above code makes animation run first then moved in y direction

Thanks for the help.. 
And can some one explaing me the concept of time with frame Animation or good example ?

Answer (score 2):

```
CCSpriteFrameCache.sharedSpriteFrameCache().addSpriteFrames("grossini_dance.plist");
            grossini = CCSprite.sprite(CCSpriteFrameCache.sharedSpriteFrameCache().spriteFrameByName("grossini_dance_01.png"));
            grossini.setPosition(CGPoint.make(60, fullheight / 3));
            addChild(grossini);
            CCAnimation anim = CCAnimation.animation("", 0.3f);
            for (int i = 2; i <10; i++) {
                anim.addFrame(CCSpriteFrameCache.sharedSpriteFrameCache().spriteFrameByName("grossini_dance_0" + i + ".png"));
            }
            // Creating animation action
            CCAction animaction = CCAnimate.action(2, anim, true);
            grossini.runAction(animaction);
```

Hope it help!!!!!!!!!!